# How to remove duplicates from printing from a loop?

Tags: java

I have been assigned the task of writing a program that lists all numbers 1 to 10000 that are the sum of two odd prime numbers squared (ex. 3^2 + 5^2 = 34), then prints the total count of these numbers. However, my program does not recognize that 3^2 + 5^2 is the same thing as 5^2 + 3^2. This causes the program to print duplicates of most of the numbers. Which in turn also affects the total count of the numbers. How can I prevent the program from printing duplicates and adding them to the total count?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/*
 * Write a program that lists all numbers 1 to 10000 that are the sum of two 
 * odd prime numbers squared (ex. 3^2 + 5^2 = 34), then prints the total 
 * count of these numbers
 */

public class labproblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 100*100 = 10000, the maximum
        int maxvalue = 100;

        ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // Checks every number until max value is reached
        for (int n = 1; n < maxvalue; n++) {
            boolean prime = true;
            // checks if n is prime

            for (int j = 2; j < n; j++) {
                if (n % j == 0) {
                    prime = false;
                    break; // exits this for loop
                }
            }
            if (prime && n != 1) {
                // adds the prime number to the list of prime numbers
                primes.add(n);
            }
        }
        // declaring/initializing
        double totalcount = 0;
        double product = 0;
        // sets i2 to the odd prime numbers
        for (int i2 : primes) {
            // sets i to the odd prime numbers
            for (int i : primes) {
                // starting at 3 first increases i, then i2
                if (i >= 3 && i2 >= 3) {
                    product = Math.pow(i, 2) + Math.pow(i2, 2);

                    // Adds 1 to the count after each execution
                    if (product <= 10000)
                        totalcount = totalcount + 1;
                    // Prints the product of the two primes squared
                    if (product <= 10000)
                        System.out.println(product);

                }
            }
        }
        // Prints the total count of the products
        System.out.println(totalcount);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please only add IDE tags like `eclipse` if your problem is related to the IDE and not just because you're using said IDE.

Comment: Only add them if `i <i2`.

Comment: Your for loops when looping over your primes is the worst choice, dont iterative over the full list in both loops. It should roughly be `for(int i = 1; i < primes.length(); i++){for(int i2=0; i2 < i; i2++){do stuff with primes[i] and primes[i2]}}`

Comment: Use the delete button beneath your question if you need to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a brute force solution, i.e. add your products to a list and don't display them again if already in the list; do something along the lines of:

```
List<Integer> products = new ArrayList<>();

if (!products.contains(product)) {
    products.add(product);
    System.out.println(product);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html). Sets do not hold duplicates.

```
    Set<Double> set = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i2 : primes) {
        for (int i : primes) {
            if (i >= 3 && i2 >= 3) {
                Double calc = Math.pow(i, 2) + Math.pow(i2, 2);
                if(calc <= 10000){
                    set.add(calc);
                }
            }
        }
    }
            //No need to count or track anything

    // For each Double called 'product' in 'set' send to an anonymous function
    set.forEach((product) -> System.out.println(product));

    System.out.println("Total Count is " + set.size());
```

This will print each unique prime calculation you want, and then the total.

Answer (score -2):

without changing much of your code, how about adding couple lines in between your code starting with ** in code snippet below.

```
**ArrayList<Integer> processed = new ArrayList<>();**
            //sets i2 to the odd prime numbers
            for (int i2 : primes) {
                **processed.add(i2);**
         // sets i to the odd prime numbers
            for (int i : primes) {
            //starting at 3 first increases i, then i2
            if (i >= 3 && i2 >= 3 **&& !processed.contains(i)**) {
                product = Math.pow(i, 2) + Math.pow(i2, 2);
```